# C# GDCM function pointer, cannot convert to SWIGTYPE

Tags: c#, swig, gdcm

I am using GDCM to read in DICOM files. As the project is in C#, I have compiled GDCM's C# wrappings with SWIG, following GDCM's manual.

Now I am trying to sort all DICOMs in a folder into Volumes (much like the [VolumeSorter example](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/VolumeSorter_8cxx-example.html) provided by GDCM, however, this is written in c++). I'm following the [SortImage2.cs](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/SortImage2_8cs-example.html) example, but this won't compile, giving me the error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to
>   'SWIGTYPE_p_f_r_q_const__gdcm__DataSet_r_q_const__gdcm__DataSet__bool'
>     New Unity Project.CSharp   ...\Scripts\SortImage2.cs    33

Here's the full example:

```
/*=========================================================================

  Program: GDCM (Grassroots DICOM). A DICOM library

  Copyright (c) 2006-2011 Mathieu Malaterre
  All rights reserved.
  See Copyright.txt or http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/Copyright.html for details.

     This software is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even
     the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
     PURPOSE.  See the above copyright notice for more information.

=========================================================================*/

using System;
using gdcm;

public class SortImage2
{
  bool mysort(DataSet ds1, DataSet ds2)
    {
    return false;
    }

  public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
    Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
    sorter.SetSortFunction( mysort );

    return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming it cannot interpret the 
Is there a way to "cast" the method to the expected type? Or is this an error in GDCM's setup of SWIG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you are describing is actually commented out as seen here:

- https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM/blob/master/Examples/Csharp/CMakeLists.txt#L15

I suspect this is a functionality that has never been finished.

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't solve my problem, but at least now I know what the real issue is. Maybe someone can remove those examples, then? I did not think of looking into the CMakeLists to see if the example is actually being created - since it's in the source code I assumed it would be used.
For anyone else needing something along these lines, it looks like the SimpleITK C# interface provides more of these features than using GDCM-Sharp directly.